# main thread not getting interrupted

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a code which prints 1 if the number being tested is a happy number and 0 otherwise.

```
class Ishappy extends Thread {
    private Integer num;
    private Thread main;
    private volatile boolean out = false;

    Ishappy(int i, Thread main) {
        this.main = main;
        num = i;
    }

    void Exit() {
        out = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!out && num != 1) {
            if(num == 1) {
                main.interrupt();
                break;
            }

            String s = num.toString();
            int temp = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); i++) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+1));
                temp += x*x;
            }
            num = temp;
        }
    }
}

public class Happy_numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte path[] = null;

        String s = "d:\\data.txt";

        try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(s)) {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fin);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            s = br.readLine();
            int num;
            while(s != null) {
                num = Integer.parseInt(s);

                Ishappy ishappy = new Ishappy(num,Thread.currentThread()); 
                ishappy.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(1);
                    continue;
                }
                if(ishappy.isAlive()) {
                    ishappy.Exit();
                    System.out.println(0);
                } else
                    System.out.println(11);

                s = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found.");
        }catch(IOException ex){
        }
    }
}
```

but the above code always prints 11 for a happy number which means `main` is never getting interrupted. Whats wrong??

The contents of data.txt are

```
1
7
22
```

Out of which 1 and 7 are happy numbers whereas 22 is not.

Comment: Your code is violating accepted Java coding standards in the way you are naming classes and methods.  Class names should NOT have embedded `'_'` characters and should use "camel case" and method names should NOT start with upper-case letters.

Comment: I have made the changes to my code. The that capital 'e' was indeed looking a little offensive. I am just using the '-' because that is what I was asked to keep the name of the file. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a need for threading here, a happy number is happy if the sum of its digits squared equals to one. if the sequence contains a number that is already tested. just terminate.

from wikipedia

> If n is not happy, then its sequence does not go to 1. What happens instead is that it ends up in the cycle.

```
public class Happy_numbers {        
    static int[]SQUARES={0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81};
    public static boolean is_happy(int n){
        return is_happy(n, new HashSet<Integer>());
    }
    public static boolean is_happy(int n, Collection<Integer> sofar){
        if(n==1) return true;
        else if(sofar.contains(n)) return false;

        sofar.add(n);

        if(n<10) {
            return is_happy(SQUARES[n], sofar);
        }

        char[]digits=String.format("%s", n).toCharArray();
        int s = 0;
        for(char c:digits){
            s+= SQUARES[Integer.valueOf(String.format("%s", c))];
        }

        return is_happy(s, sofar);
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Collection<Integer> c1 = Arrays.asList(
                1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97, 
                100, 103, 109, 129, 130, 133, 139, 167, 176, 188, 190, 192, 193, 203, 208, 
                219, 226, 230, 236, 239, 262, 263, 280, 291, 293, 301, 302, 310, 313, 319, 
                320, 326, 329, 331, 338, 356, 362, 365, 367, 368, 376, 379, 383, 386, 391, 
                392, 397, 404, 409, 440, 446, 464, 469, 478, 487, 490, 496 );
        Collection<Integer> c2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(c1.size());
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int c = 1;
        for(int i=0;i<500;i++){
            if(is_happy(i)) {
                System.out.print(i+", ");
                if(c++ % 20 == 0) System.out.println();
                c2.add(i);
            }

        }
        t = System.currentTimeMillis()-t;
        System.out.println("\nTIME : " + t);
        System.out.println("Got them all < 500 : " + (c2.containsAll(c1) && c1.containsAll(c2)));
    }
}
```

It can be also further improved by using a map, or any caching technique so if a number is happy and you have calculated this number before, no need to do the same thing again. From wikipediea,

> The happy numbers below 500 are:
>   1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97, 100, 103, 109,
>   129, 130, 133, 139, 167, 176, 188, 190, 192, 193, 203, 208, 219, 226, 230, 236, 239, 262, 
>   263, 280, 291, 293, 301, 302, 310, 313, 319, 320, 326, 329, 331, 338, 356, 362, 365, 367, 368, 
>   376, 379, 383, 386, 391, 392, 397, 404, 409, 440, 446, 464, 469, 478, 487, 490, 496 
>   (sequence A007770 in OEIS).

and the above code needs 435 to get all the happy numbers below 500.

```
1, 7, 10, 13, 19, 23, 28, 31, 32, 44, 49, 68, 70, 79, 82, 86, 91, 94, 97, 100, 
103, 109, 129, 130, 133, 139, 167, 176, 188, 190, 192, 193, 203, 208, 219, 226, 230, 236, 239, 262, 
263, 280, 291, 293, 301, 302, 310, 313, 319, 320, 326, 329, 331, 338, 356, 362, 365, 367, 368, 376, 
379, 383, 386, 391, 392, 397, 404, 409, 440, 446, 464, 469, 478, 487, 490, 496, 
TIME : 435
Got them all < 500 : true
```

So, I have made some changes to your code to allow remembering what have been calculated so far, at least for the current number.

```
public class Happy_numbers {

    static class Ishappy extends Thread {
        private Integer num;
        private Thread main;
        private volatile boolean out = false;

        private boolean unhappy = false;

        Ishappy(int i, Thread main) {
            this.main = main;
            num = i;
        }

        public boolean isUnhappy() {
            return unhappy;
        }

        void Exit() {
            out = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Set<Integer> sofar = new HashSet<Integer>();
            while(!out && num != 1) {
                unhappy = sofar.contains(num);
                if(num == 1 || unhappy) {
                    main.interrupt();
                    break;
                }

                sofar.add(num);

                String s = num.toString();
                int temp = 0;
                for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+1));
                    temp += x*x;
                }
                num = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        byte path[] = null;

        String s = "./data.txt";

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(s);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        int num;
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(s);

            Ishappy ishappy = new Ishappy(num,Thread.currentThread()); 
            ishappy.start();
            ishappy.join();
            if(ishappy.isUnhappy()){
                System.out.println("Number ["+num+"] is not happy");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Number ["+num+"] is happy");
            }
        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Number [1] is happy
Number [7] is happy
Number [22] is not happy
```

**EDIT**

I have found the reason why the main thread dosen't get interrupted.

in the main while loop, you check the num being 1 or not, if it was one, you wont get to the if condition that checks for the value of num and based on which interrupts the main thread.

```
public class Happy_numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String s = "./data.txt";

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(s);
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fin);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        int num;
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(s);

            Ishappy ishappy = new Ishappy(num,Thread.currentThread()); 
            ishappy.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(1);
                continue;   // here is another problem, infinit loop
            }
            if(ishappy.isAlive()) {
                ishappy.Exit();
                System.out.println(0);
            } else
                System.out.println(11);

        }
        br.close();
        in.close();
        fin.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

and here is Ihappy class

```
class Ishappy extends Thread {
    private volatile Integer num;
    private Thread main;
    private volatile boolean out = false;

    Ishappy(int i, Thread main) {
        this.main = main;
        num = i;
    }

    void Exit() {
        out = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!out) {   /// <- here was the problem
            if(num.intValue() == 1) { // since this condition will break out
                main.interrupt();     // of the loop, you do not need it in the
                break;                // while condition
            }

            String s = num.toString();
            int temp = 0;
            for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); i++) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i+1));
                temp += x*x;
            }
            num = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
1
1
0
DONE
```

Comment: Well.. yeah. I guess I was supposed to keep a record of all the numbers that have been tested, but I still can't understand why isn't the main thread getting interrupted. And I am not sure but I guess join() was added by java 6, and I am supposed to write code in java 1.5.

Comment: Then you can use Thread.sleep(1000) between try/catch. ignore any exception because the thread must be interrupted using my method. By the way, using join is not useful in this scenario. Because it will wait for the thread to finish its duty or until it get interrupted.

Comment: For the record **try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(s))** is a java 1.7 style of code not 1.5

Comment: Oh thanks.. I didn't know that. And ya the join was not much use as it always waits for the thread to terminate. I just can't understand why isn't the main thread getting interrupted.

Comment: yeah.. :) actually that was the code I wrote before adding the `num != 1` condition to the while loop but I forgot to add the statement `s = br.readLine();` before `continue` while handling the exception and it was just running in an infinite loop. Thanks for bringing it to my attention though. Answer accepted.

Comment: I have just read @Gray answer, and found that he did mention the reason for why the main thread is not interrupted

Answer (score 1):

As I read your program, the first time through the main loop, a new `IsHappy` thread will be forked with `num` set to `1`.  In the `IsHappy.run()` method, if `num` is `1` it immediately quits.

```
while(!out && num != 1)
```

`main` will sleep and then print `11` because the thread is no longer running.

```
if(ishappy.isAlive()) {
    ishappy.Exit();
    System.out.println(0);
} else
   System.out.println(11);
```

Is that not what you expect?  I think you should learn how to use a debugger.  Here's a good tutorial on how to [debug your program in Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

If the number `7` is processed then the `IsHappy.run()` method will spin, setting `num` to be `49` (`7*7`) over and over.  `main` will then see that `IsHappy` is still alive and will call `IsHappy.Exit()` and will print `0`.

If the number `21` is processed then the `IsHappy.run()` method will spin, setting `num` to be `5` (`2*2+1*1`) over and over.  `main` will again `Exit()` the thread and print `0`.

So I guess your output is:

```
11
0
0
```

The `main` thread will never be interrupted because the `while` loop will stop it from running if `num == 1`.

Couple of other comments about your code.  THis may be test code so it doesn't matter but to be pedantic:

- Never catch and just throw away an exception (see your `IOException` catch).  At least put a comment in an empty catch block explaining *why* you don't care about the exception.
- Your thread is spinning doing its calculations.  This is not a good use of resources obviously.
- You are not closing any of your input streams or readers.  Always use a try/finally when dealing with these.
- `Exit()` method should start with a lowercase letter.  A better name for the method would be `stop`.

Comment: Your comments about the code are spot on ... but I'd argue that in some cases it matters even in test code!  1) If something unexpected is going wrong even in test code, the OP should care about it, if he wants the tests to produce meaningful answers. 4) He >>is<< expecting other people to read his code.

Comment: Well man I didn't bother with exceptions because I am a newbee and I just wanted to keep things simple. And no the thread is not just spinning around doing calculations, infact the output of the code is coming out to be `11 11 0`. And yes I could have overloaded the exit() method in the Thread class but I cannot do that with stop(), it is declared as final in the Thread class and it cannot be overriden anymore. I just can't understand why the main() thread is not getting interrupted. Please help me if you can.

Comment: And also please tell me how can we debug multithreaded code as the debugger never steps into the the code for the threads. I am using NetBeans by the way.

Comment: @user1232138 Your thread code spins for a second, calculating the result over and over and over again until the main thread calls `Exit()`.  Is that really what you want?  If the output is `11 11 0` then I guess you've overflowed the integer arithmetic and `num` rolls around to be 1.  I'm surprised at that.

Comment: @user1232138 Debugging should work with threads with a particular thread stopping at the breakpoint.  I'm not sure how netbeans would complicate matters.  Can you unit test your code directly and debug it?